# Reading intel assembly 8086 listing file

Tags: assembly

Here is my listing file for a program. However, the question I'm asked is
the significance of **F0** on line 20. I know the first column represents the address offset and the third column represents the instruction, but how do we figure out what the data means here?

```
 1 ; 
 2 ; 
 3 ;
 4                                 section .data
 5
 6 00000000 0102030405             number: db 1,2,3,4,5
 7 00000005 00                     sum: db 0
 8
 9
 10                                section .text
 11                                        global _start
 12
 13                                 _start:
 14 00000000 B905000000            keith: mov ecx, 5
 15 00000005 B800000000            ron:   mov eax, 0
 16 0000000A BB[00000000]                 mov ebx, number
 17 0000000F 0203                  again: add al, [ebx]
 18 00000011 81C301000000                 add ebx,1
 19 00000017 81E901000000                 sub ecx,1
 20 0000001D 75F0                         jnz again
 21 0000001F A2[05000000]                 mov [sum], al
 22
 23 00000024 B801000000                   mov eax,1
 24 00000029 BB00000000                   mov ebx,0
 25 0000002E CD80                         int 80h
```

Comment: `jnz again` has opcode `75` is a [*short jump*](http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/2bytejumps.htm) (a *relative* jump). `F0` read as a signed byte offset, is `-10h` which is how far away the `again:` label is from the IP after `jnz`. In other words, `F0 = 0F - 1F` when done in signed byte arithmetic. It tells the CPU to jump *back* `10h` bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opcode `75` is a [*short jump*](http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/2bytejumps.htm). A *short jump* is a relative jump that is less than 128 bytes away forward or backward from the *instruction pointer* (IP) of the instruction that follows the jump instruction. (NOTE: in the standard CPU fetch-execute cycle, an instruction is fetched, and then the IP is incremented to the next instruction *before* the fetched instruction is executed.)

```
 16 0000000A BB[00000000]                 mov ebx, number
 17 0000000F 0203                  again: add al, [ebx]
 18 00000011 81C301000000                 add ebx,1
 19 00000017 81E901000000                 sub ecx,1
 20 0000001D 75F0                         jnz again
 21 0000001F A2[05000000]                 mov [sum], al
```

In this case, your full opcode is: `75F0`. That's a short jump (if Z flag is 0) a distance from the next IP represented by the *signed* byte value, `F0`. The signed value of `F0h`, taken as a 2's complement signed byte, is minus `10h` and is computed as:

```
  0000000F ; address of "again:" label
- 0000001F ; address of instruction after "jnz"
----------
        F0 ; difference in addresses
```

This tells the CPU to jump *back* `-10h` byte locations from the following IP in order to get to the `again:` label.

The fact that the distance to jump was so short, the assembler was able to use the *short jump*. Otherwise, if it were greater than 128 bytes away, a different jump opcode would be needed (*e.g.*, *near jump* if it's within the 64kB segment - otherwise a *far jump* is needed).

Comment: Oh I see. But how do you know that 75 is the opcode in this case? Some of the instructions are 6 bytes, others are 5 bytes and the jnz instruction is only 2 bytes. Had I known that 75 was the opcode, that could have hinted me to figure out that F0 was actually on offset...

Comment: @Dimitri If you look up "x86 opcodes" they're all defined specifically for the function they perform. How many bytes the opcode is would be determined from looking at the first byte or two of the opcode. [This link](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_147.html), for example, shows a few different jump opcodes. Whether it's *far*, *near*, or *short* can be determined by the first byte.

Comment: Great! I'll have a look. Sometimes finding information on stuff you can barely ask questions for is a difficult task. Thanks for the help!